# Jquery change image back when user reclick

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#favour").click(function(){
        $("#favour").css({background:'different image..'});
        $.(post...)//POST BOOLEAN HERE
    });

})

<button id="favour">
```

I have an add favour button, use jquery post and change css.

When it click. it will change to different image and post TRUE to DB.

But what I need is, When I click it again, it will change image back and post FALSE.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#favour").click(function(){
       var obj = $(this);
       if(obj.attr('data-isFavorite') == 'yes')
       {
         obj.attr('data-isFavorite','no');
         $("#favour").css({background:'different image..'});
          $.(post...)//POST FALSE HERE
       }
       else
       {
         obj.attr('data-isFavorite','yes');
         $("#favour").css({background:'different image..'});
         $.(post...)//POST TRUE HERE
       }

});

})


<button id="favour">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boolflg = true;
    $("#favour").click(function(){
        var bgimg = boolflg ? 'trueimage' : 'falseimage';
         $("#favour").css({background:bgimg});
        if(boolflg) {
          $.(post...)//POST TRUE HERE
        } else {
          $.(post...)//POST FALSE HERE
        }
        boolflg = !boolflg;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the background image, store the current image in a variable. When the next click happens, set the background to your stored image.

Answer (score 0):

take one variable say for eg. flag = 0; then in post call check value of flag and change background according to value

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isPost=true;
    $("#favour").click(function(){
        var image=(isPost==true) ? 'image-1' : 'image-2'; // toggle image
        $("#favour").css({background:image});//you can use class here
        $.(post...)
        isPost=(isPost==true) ? false : true; // toggling isPost variable
    });    
})
```

Comment: the line "isPost=(isPost==true) ? false : true;" can be written as isPost = !isPost also...